# How to find the required inlet velocity/pressure to achieve 0.5 m/s in one part of the underground tunnel?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have this problem here related with tunnel and ventilation.

As you can see at the picture below, it is a top view of the tunnel. 
The tunnel has an inlet and an outlet. The air flows from the inlet on the left and exits at the outlet on the right. There is one branch/drift to this main tunnel road (it's with the label "0.5 m/s").

At the end of this 0.5 m/s drift, it is required for the airflow to achieve a velocity magnitude of **0.5 m/s at the end of the drift**. The pressure at the outlet surface is also **already defined as 120 Pa**.

My question is, how to find the required inlet air pressure or velocity for achieving that 0.5 m/s at the end of the drift? My fluid dynamics knowledge is pretty bad so I need your help please. The dimensions and the figure of the tunnel is well illustrated in that picture.

I will be grateful for any help that you could provide.

[image: Illustration of my problem]

Comment: 1 meter/second? Is it a simple case of mass conservation, because the velocity is slow enough to be considered incompressible.

Comment: Uppss.. sorry, yeah it's more of an engineering question and I'm a first timer on this stackexchange thing.. I'll figure out what should I do after reading that meta post.. Perhaps I should just delete this question?

Comment: Sometimes people on this site are a little persnickety. Don't be concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this correct, but I think you can solve this with an energy balance, the equation of state and the mass flow:

Assuming $\dot{v}$ is zero, no losses in the pipe:
$$\dot{E}_{kin}=\frac{1}{2} \dot{m} v^2$$
$$\dot{m}=\rho A V$$
$$P = \rho R T$$
Substitute them, and evaluate them for both the incoming and outgoing location(s)

On second thought, this might be a bit over simplified. The situation at the corner is quite difficult, sharp corner -> separation. It's not easy to determine which part of the air takes the turn, and which part goes straight..  One might even say that there is nothing to force the air from not going on straight?